# EFCore 2.1 and Pomelo MySql - Left Join LINQ Query Not working

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, ef-core-2.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have two tables with the following relationship: "Order" having one to many relationship with "OrderTasks"

I am trying to run the following SQL statement through LINQ:

```
    SELECT o.*
    FROM `Order` AS `o`
    LEFT JOIN `OrderTask` AS `t` ON `o`.`Id` = `t`.`OrderId`
    where t.Id is null
```

According to the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#left-join), this is supposed to be the LINQ query:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = from o in _context.Orders
                                       join t in _context.OrderTasks
                                           on o.Id equals t.OrderId into grouping
                                       from t in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       select o;
```

But it is generating the below:

```
   SELECT `o`.*
   FROM `Order` AS `o`
```

I am using EFCore 2.1 and Pomelo Mysql provider against mysql version 5.6. Any idea what needs to be adjusted to get the left join working? Thank you in advance!

Comment: OrderTasks do not participate in the filtering or selection and most likely where not included into SQL as redundant.
Try to add condition 
    where t == null

Comment: No luck, still get the same sql statement with no left joins. I ran the exact linq query through LINQPad and it works as expected.

Comment: You may want to open an issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762246/efcore-2-1-and-pomelo-mysql-left-join-linq-query-not-working but note that I think EF Core 2.1 isn't supported anymore; can you update to EF.Core 2.2 or 3.1?

Comment: I can't update to 2.1 at this time unfortunately. Are you thinking this is an efcore issue or pomelo?

Comment: Oops; wrong link in my previous comment. I meant: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: I don't know if it's EFCore or Pomelo; I just know that 2.1 isn't listed as a supported version here: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#compatibility
Can you not even update to 2.2?

Comment: This is not a Pomelo issue and LEFT JOINs *do* also work with EF Core 2.1 in general. See [#1084](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1084) on GitHub, where the discussion continues. @Emon On a side note, why can't you update/upgrade? Pomelo 3.1.1 is .NET Core 2.0+ compatible. See [Compatibility: EF Core and .NET Standard](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#ef-core-and-net-standard) for the compatibility table.